# Django ListView not showing recently created items

Tags: python, django

I have an app with lots of class based views. In some of my ListViews, the items recently created are not being displayed. My models are like:

```
# models.py
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

And

```
# views.py
class ChildListView(ListView):
    model = Child
    template = 'child.html'
```

The thing is that, whenever I create an object from a CreateView, it doesn't appear in my list view. I thought it was because of sqlite in my developing server, but it happens also in MySQL. If I restart the service, it works normally. Any idea?

Comment: Doesn't appear means, with a view that render the whole list include the latest, after refreshing the browser it still won't show ? Have to restart the server ?

Comment: It means it won't show, even if I reload the browser or if I get to the page via an Ajax call. I have to restart the Django process (manage.py runserver) in order for items to show